# Writing an .htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm not great at writing rewrite rules, but this has me confused.  I want to make a rewrite rule for url's of the form

`http://www.test.com/ENG/help.htm#PST
http://www.test.com/JPN/help.htm#GMT-0900`

(where the second part is either ENG or JPN, then always help.htm, then # and a timezone abbreviation)

to redirect to

`/en/help#PST
/jp/help#GMT-0900`

I've tried lots of variations on the following:

`RewriteRule ^/ENG/help.htm /en/help [NC,QSA,L]`

just to see if I could get /ENG/help.htm to redirect to en/help, but for some reason this is always failing (no redirects are happening at all, so I guess for some reason it's not detecting the URL's I expect it to..?), and I'm getting really confused now as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash from your URI and part after `#` doesn't even reach to server so that cannot be added back in resulting URI. You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ENG/help\.htm$ /en/help#PST [NC,NE,L,R]
```

Comment: So, is there a difference between .conf files and .htaccess in terms of rewrite rules or something?  Your answer worked in an online .htaccess checker, but it did not work for my site until I added the leading slash back in, but thanks, because it definitely helped me out.

Comment: My updated rule will work both from .conf and .htaccess files. Yes this is the difference that leading slash is not matched in .htaccess